# angular-cli --prod flag errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli

ng build and ng serve commands, result in no errors and the whole application runs smoothly.

Whereas

```
ng build --prod
ng serve --prod
```

These commands run without error in the terminal. But in the application, clicking some of the links result in errors showing up in the console.
I didn't know how to go about debugging this.
I tried,

```
ng serve --prod -sm
```

It was an improvement but still have no idea what to do with the errors.

The thing is the same codebase runs smoothly without the --prod flag.

Attaching Screenshots,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVSE9.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsnNu.jpg

The second screenshot reports a common comprehendible error which I understand, but I do not know how to fix it, as I simply do not understand why these errors won't come up when not using the --prod flag.

Some guidance would be nice. Thanks.

EDIT:

otherreports.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { EqualValidator } from './equal-validator.directive';
import { LbdModule } from '../lbd/lbd.module';
import { FormsRoutes } from './otherreports.routing';
import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';
import { NouisliderModule } from 'ng2-nouislider';
import { JWBootstrapSwitchModule } from 'jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2';


import { FuelReportComponent } from './fuelreport/fuelreport.component';
import { IdlingReportComponent } from './idlingreport/idlingreport.component';
import { IgnitionReportComponent } from './ignitionreport/ignitionreport.component';
import { OverspeedComponent } from './overspeedreport/overspeedreport.component';
import { StoppageReportComponent } from './stoppagereport/stoppagereport.component';
import { ComingSoonComponent } from './comingsoon/comingsoon.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(FormsRoutes),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        TagInputModule,
        NouisliderModule,
        JWBootstrapSwitchModule,
        LbdModule
    ],
    declarations: [
          FuelReportComponent,
          IdlingReportComponent,
          IgnitionReportComponent,
          OverspeedComponent,
          StoppageReportComponent,
          ComingSoonComponent,
          EqualValidator
    ]
})

export class OtherReportsModule {}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of otherreports.module.ts? Also the imports of it

Comment: In the first picture, you are trying to access a variable that is not defined. Could you please go a little bit further and take a look where actually is trying to access that variable. The second image is telling you the module OtherReportsModule is not stored in './otherreports' folder. Maybe the module is stored somewhere else. If this information is not enough, give us more information about the project and the error message.

Comment: @Bogdan: Both images are telling the same. The first is just the unreadable error of an build without sourcemaps

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov But if that is the case, why is the same error not occurring when I do not use the --prod flag. Afaik, the imports and their paths are correct. Anyway, I'll edit the question and post relevant code.

Comment: All the other routes in the application are working fine. Its just that this module's routes won't work. And just in production mode.

Comment: surprisingly, I uninstalled node v8.4.0 and installed v6.11.2
And now everything works. But why?!